# Deep copy constructor array class C++

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, copy-constructor, deep-copy

Take the class given below as an example, it is basically just an array within a class.

```
class MyArray{
    public:
        MyArray(int maxCapacity = 1024){
            ptr = new int[maxCapacity];
            numOfElements = 0;
        }
        ~MyArray();
    private:
        int numOfElements; // current number of elements in array
        int *ptr; //pointer to the array data
};
```

What is the best way to implement a copy constructor for such a class.

Me and a friend are having an argument about it.

My belief is that it would require you to have another capacity variable that stores the maxCapacity argument of the constructor, however when given this question in an exam this variable was not included.

My friend believes that performing a copy that creates the new array based off the value of the numOfElements variable (in some arbitrary way) would suffice.

My issue with his suggestion is that this is not strictly a 'deep copy' as I would think a deep copy would imply that the new object is identical in every way except memory location.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Without more information about the purpose of the class, your question cannot be answered. However, it can be definitively stated that your suggestion that *"a deep copy would imply that the new object is identical in every way except memory location"* is wrong.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of what a deep copy is supposed to be.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley if you are going to 'definitively' state something I would ask that you back that up with some form of reasoning, if i wanted to be told i am wrong without reasoning i would have listened to my friend, instead i came here for an answer and some reasoning. Also what other information would you think is neccessary to answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to implement a copy constructor for such a class.

Well - the algorithm is quite simple. When copying A into B (so doing `MyArray A; MyArray B(A)`), the way here is:

1. Allocate the needed space to store `A.numOfElements` elements,
2. Set `B.numOfElements` to `A.numOfElements`,
3. Copy `numOfElements` elements from `A.ptr` to `B.ptr` (possibly calling `memcpy` or - preferably - `std::copy`).

And taking into account your second concern:

> My belief is that it would require you to have another capacity variable that stores the maxCapacity argument of the constructor (...) My friend believes that performing a copy that creates the new array based off the value of the numOfElements variable (in some arbitrary way) would suffice.

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) (text emphasized by me):

> An object copy is an action in computing where a data object has **its attributes** copied to another object of the same data type.

So the answer is: yes, it would suffice, since `maxCapacity` isn't an attribute of `MyArray`. A **deep copy** is made when you actually **copy** the contents of one object into another (not just point to existing ones like when doing a *shallow copy*). In this case, since `A` actually stores `numOfElements` elements, we can assume that - even if it **can** contain more - the rest is just rubbish, so we don't need to copy it.

On the other hand - the class is probably improperly designed. When accessing elements of `ptr`, there is no way to check if we're accessing the memory we can, or trying to set memory that doesn't belong to us. Since the class itself doesn't store information about the array size, there is no way it can warn us about overflowing (well it can "*crash*", but that's probably not the best way to design your classes). And although it's a peculiar design, it doesn't interfere with actually copying the contents of `MyArray`.

Comment: Your item (1) is not right. `B` is a new object, you need to initialize the member variables. There is no need to check whether `ptr` is NULL, etc.

Comment: @RSahu you're right, the question is about the constructor, not `operator=`. Guess I went a step too far there :) Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> My belief is that it would require you to have another capacity variable that stores the maxCapacity argument of the constructor, however when given this question in an exam this variable was not included.

Let's say you have:

```
MyStruct a(100);
MyStruct b(a);
```

Once `a` has been constructed, there is no trace of the capacity of `a.ptr`. You won't be able to perform any validity check on the index used to access the data contained in `a.ptr`. Strictly speaking, you don't *need* to store the maximum capacity to use `a` but it sure will be helpful in debugging and error checking.

However, if you don't store the maximum capacity in the class, you will have to assume some maximum capacity for `b`, which might be different than the maximum capacity of `a`.

You said:

> My friend believes that performing a copy that creates the new array based off the value of the numOfElements variable (in some arbitrary way) would suffice.

This is subjective. It depends on the usage of the objects in your application. If you don't expect the size of `b.ptr` to ever exceed the size of `a.numOfElements`, then your friend has a point. You could use that as the maximum capacity for `b`.

You said:

> My issue with his suggestion is that this is not strictly a 'deep copy' as I would think a deep copy would imply that the new object is identical in every way except memory location.

I think, from a strictly theoretical stand point, you are right. From a usability stand point, your friend's suggestion might suffice. Once again, it depends on how these objects are used in your application.

**In Conclusion**

I think having `maxCapacity` as a member variable is a better design. The extra memory is not significant. The extra code to deal with it won't too much either.

If you are allowed to use `std::vector`, you should use that without thinking too much. It will be a better option than managing memory in your class.